# How do you use a windows key shortcut in chrome remote desktop?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, remote-access, remote

Chrome remote desktop is like VNC or like Windows remote desktop.. but implemented by Google.  It lets you view a computer remotely.  The computer to be viewed has to run some software and then it can be viewed from another computer from the chrome "web browser".  Neither computer has to run any server, so no port forwarding is necessary at the NAPT router.

My question regarding chrome remote desktop, is how do you use the windows key in chrome remote desktop?

e.g. the computer you're connected from has a keyboard with the windows key on it, but if you do e.g. winkey+R on the local computer, then it brings up the run dialog on the local computer.. When I want it to be the case that doing winkey+R on the local computer's keyboard, brings up the run dialog box on the remote computer.

I understand that chrome remote desktop has two options. Remote access, and Remote support.

[image]

Remote access being more for you accessing your own computers. And remote support being more for you accessing other peoples computers and a temporary code set up.  I doubt it makes a difference here but i'm using "remote access".  I just tried it with the "remote support" option, and same issue.

If I tap the windows key, it opens both start menus, the one on the local computer and the one on the remote computer, which is ok..

If I tap the windows key with R, then it opens the start menu if the run dialog on the local computer, but only opens the start menu on the remote computer.

Comment: If you control the remote computer, you could install AutoHotkey and replace the Windows key by another key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a key combination that mimics the "Windows Key" press when using Remote Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/417253/is-there-a-key-combination-that-mimics-the-windows-key-press-when-using-remote)

Answer (score 0):

You can use screen keyboard on remote keyboard, like `osk` in Windows.
`osk` is built-in. To open:

1. Open cmd (you can find it in Start menu)
2. Write `osk` and press Enter.